# How do i check my SQLite database values in eclipse?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I created a app and added some tables, columns and some info in it and i want to check it, how do i do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch to `DDMS` perpective(Window > Open Perpective > DDMS).

Find out your database's db file in file explorer. Select it.

Export it by clicking on the button in the top right corner of the UI.(ie; Pull the file from from the device)

Use SQLiteman to view the data.

Hope it helps.

Comment: i did it and didnt found my db :/ haha

Comment: in my case, it is located in ddms > file explorer > data > data > my app name.

Comment: well same as mine should be but i dont see the folder there :/

Comment: Tried in the root data folder?

Comment: ur db file should be there in the sd card or phone memory. u have to find it out. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are running your app on the phone, you cant access your internal storage unless it is rooted. If that is your case simply run the app on a virtual device, then go to **DDMS** perspective, from there data/data/yourapplication/database/urdb.db then pull the db on the your computer and explore it with the tools stated above.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Motodev Studio allows for database browsing.
http://developer.motorola.com/tools/motodevstudio/?utm_campaign=mhp01092012&utm_source=mhp&utm_medium=mws
Or you could just export the database to your desktop, for example, and then browse it with the Firefox SQLite plugin.

Answer (score 0):

you can query the database from your android code to do this.
check the link http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2012/08/sqlite-database.html where you can find creating table , inserting data into tables and retrieving it . Or use SQLite Database Browser http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/ to check the values without using the code

Answer (score 0):

use **Sqlite Database Browser** tool to see the your Sqlite database.
Go to the DDMS and export your application database and open this database in Sqlite Database Browser

Answer (score 0):

This post on [how to access sqlite database on Android](http://code4reference.com/2012/06/access-sqlite-database-android/), will help you out. There is one [mozilla plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) which can also help you to see the database.